# Is it possible to kill hair particles

Tags: particles

I am trying to make shaving animation where object interacts with hair and at the same time kills it but I cant really find a way to kill hair particles. I tried using kill particles in collision menu but it doesn't seem to work for hair, anyone knows how to do it? Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Well you can use textures and weight paint maps for the density of the hair. So if you have a map with an overall weight of 1, there will be particles. If you take a brush and paint some areas with 0, I guess this might work... but I'm not sure if the remaining particles will be affected by this, too. Like, when you say it should be 1.000 particles and reduce the area, then the particles will be distributed differently. So this is just an idea, not a real answer. Maybe someone else can give better advice.

Comment: Hair particles are always dead. They cannot be killed like the Emitter particles on hit. But it works with textures to control the density. You can use Dynamic Paint and bake it to an Image Sequence. You need to tick Auto Refresh in the settings. [Dynamic weight paint maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12270/how-to-animate-weight-painting) I couldn't get to work with the particle system :(